# Join Dense_Rank query result to view on calculated field

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, dense-rank

I have a SQL view where I am adding transformations/calculated columns etc.

One of the columns needs to be true or false, based on the dense rank of a calculated ID over a category being < 12.

I have the results I need over the category in a seperate query

```
SELECT [cat], CASE WHEN DENSE_RANK () OVER (ORDER BY COUNT([id]) desc) < 12 THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END As 'Top'
FROM [i].[dbo].[view]
GROUP BY [cat]
```

This is giving me a table with two columns, the category name and a true/false based on the calculation (which is correct).

My problem stands in trying to join the result of this query back into the view that was used to create it.

I want to add the true/false value as a new column, joining on `[id]`. I have tried to use join functions, but as the `[id]` column was calculated as part of the view, it's throwing me errors that it's an invalid column name.

How do I go about joining the results to the view?

Thank you.

---

Edited to include sample data/results.

Right now my view contains lots of columns.

ID - is calculated by COALESCE, so it isn't in the original datatable, just a view column.

A very rough example of my table could be

```
A | B | C | D | Cat | ID
- | - | - | - | Red | 1
- | - | - | - | Red | 2
- | - | - | - | Blu | 1
- | - | - | - | Yel | 1
```

In reality, there are about 30 categories and about 5000 distinct id's.

My query results returns a two column table

```
Cat | Top
Red | True
Blu | False
Yel | True
--- | ---
--- | ---
```

What I need, is to either join the query results with the view, or to somehow include the query itself in the view select statement so my view reads

```
A | B | C | D | Cat | ID | top
- | - | - | - | Red | 1  | TRUE
- | - | - | - | Red | 2  | TRUE
- | - | - | - | Blu | 1  | FALSE
- | - | - | - | Yel | 1  | TRUE
```

I hope this clears it up for everyone. Thank you.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results to clarify your question.

Comment: use cte or subquery to solve your problem

Comment: @RF1991 Can you please elaborate? Will the results of the subquery update as more data is ingested and the top dense ranked categories might change?

Comment: your query is not a table or view, by using cte,subquery ,
Table Variable and temp table you will build a virtual table that enable you to join your query with other table

Answer (score 0):

Your table

```
declare @R TABLE (
   A   VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL 
  ,B   VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL
  ,C   VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL
  ,D   VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL
  ,Cat VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL
  ,ID  INT  NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO @R(A,B,C,D,Cat,ID) VALUES 
('-','-','-','-','Red',1),
('-','-','-','-','Red',2),
('-','-','-','-','Blu',1), 
('-','-','-','-','Yel',1);
```

result of query

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (
   Cat VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
  ,Top1 VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO @T(Cat ,Top1) VALUES 
('Red','True'), 
('Blu','False'),
('Yel','True');
```

you should use your result query in cte, subquery , Table Variable and temp table in order to join it with your table

```
SELECT A,B,C,D,R.Cat,ID,Top1 FROM @R R
JOIN (SELECT Cat ,Top1 FROM @T) T
ON R.Cat=T.Cat
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm a newbie to all this. Do I have to declare a table for a view? There are a feral amount of columns that I would need to declare - plus this isn't close to the last calculated column I need. Thanks.

Comment: I have used declare in order to solve your problem,you don't need it, use subquery to solve your problem